# Redirecting https requests to a subdomain with Apache2 and mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has an SSL certificate on a subdomain, let's call it https:// ssl.maindomain.com. I want to redirect all https requests on https:// maindomain.com to https:// ssl.maindomain.com, while still keeping all http requests on http:// maindomain.com.

Is this even possible? I've googled and nothing really came up.

(The spaces in the protocols are because I cannot post hyperlinks)

Thanks,
Luke

**edit:**  Figured it out. This did the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ssl.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Please answer to yourself and check it as valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rewrite module in apache ... the lines you need to place into the vhost for **maindomain.com** would look something like this (**please test first, this is untested**):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://ssl.maindomain.com$1
```

Basically, turn on the engine (line 1), if the the https is "on" (line 2) execute the next line: rewrite the url to ssl main domain (line 3). The third line would work like this:

> https://maindomain.com/mypage to https://ssl.maindomain.com/mypage
>
> https://maindomain.com/ to https://ssl.maindomain.com/

This would only trigger on the condition (RewriteCond) that https is on. When https is off, i.e., http, your traffic should continue go to http://maindomain.com/

Try it out in a test server before running this in production in case this interferes with some other rules. HTH.